# Man stranded on alien planet, dies alone, alien creatures under water

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I'm looking for help to identify a short story. The man was stranded on an alien planet (crash landed, I think) and ends up dying there alone. He is on a little boat at the end (that he made, maybe) and dies on it. There are alien creatures that swim in the water under him sometimes too.

Comment: Do you know when you read it?

Comment: In about 1995, I don't know if at that time it was recent or not (I think it was in a collection of short stories from the library).

Comment: Interesting. I saw a tv show (The Outer Limits "Worlds Apart") that had this story in it. The man in the boat crash landed on a planet and contacted NASA though a wormhole. He was on an ocean planet in a zodiac style boat - and large creatures that swam beneath him. The story had a very sad ending.

Comment: @DonDontBeKnownBeKnown - Was there any indication that the show was based on a short story?

Comment: I TOO am looking for this story, I borrowed the book from the library in the late seventies, and have been looking for it for the ;ast thirty years..... the boat was a coracle, he was able to eat the vegetation and realised that he could bbreath when he became seasick and had to remove his helmet.....

Comment: Yes I am also looking for this book a read it in the 80's.
Starts with large space ship from earth going to colonise alien planet, man takes landing craft for test flight, an explosion on main ship kills everybody. He then lands alone on planet in land craft, try's a few locations on planet, ends up on island, where it is a battle for survival, Ends up with him get sicker and sicker, then find an underwater alien as he sits on the shore, and in the end he dies

Answer (score 6):

"Shipwreck" by Charles Logan

> A starship blows up in a nuclear accident  in orbit around a planet of the star Capella, leaving alive only a few astronauts who were in the landing craft nearby. Only one escapes a lethal dose of radiation.
>
> Isidore Tansis, the only one who is not sick, has no choice but to land on the planet, which is barely able to sustain human life - and once down there all his companions die, and the novel begins with Tansis having just buried them.
>
> He now has to face the fact that he will have to spend the rest of his life on the planet, with not the slightest hope of ever again meeting or speaking to another human being, because it is known that no other spaceships are within many light-years of Capella.
>
> Tansis suffers terrible loneliness and hallucinations, causing him to treat the ship's computer like a physiotherapist.
>
> He undergoes hardships during expeditions to find food and resources and makes great efforts to communicate with the native sea creatures who "speak" by dilating their eye pupils.
> He dies lonely on a beach at the end.

Sourced from this review ..
http://www.foxall.com.au/users/mje/Shipwrek.htm