# Looking for a 70s sci fi novel featuring a marooned pilot

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the name of a novel which featured a young pilot on a generation ship which explodes when going into orbit. The name of the hero is Tannis Isadore but I could be wrong or the spelling incorrect. At the start of the novel he rescues eight other highly injured colonist and lands in the drop ship prepped for a 30 day stay. When these eventually all die, the story really begins and concerns his heroic efforts to extend his life. Eventually he dies a very sad death.

Comment: Sorry FuzzyBoots but your way off the mark with your reply. The planet is benign and he does have a limited telepathic link to some seal type creatures . However the gist of the story is his survival against the odds .

Comment: I'm sorry - my answer was for another question!

Comment: @LeeEckhardt: you can and should delete your answer if it was posted in  error. Otherwise it is likely to attract downvotes.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89304/man-stranded-on-alien-planet-dies-alone-alien-creatures-under-water

Answer (score 5):

WARNING SPOILERS AHEAD.

I read this book in I think the late 70s. After much hard searching, I found it's "Shipwreck" by Charles Logan (1975).

The protagonist was named Isidore Tansis, born during the voyage. He was the sole survivor of a catastrophic explosion on the colony starship as it was approaching the target world. Tansis is able to land in a lifeboat and sets up a home. He makes a wind generator; he had intended to bury the pylons' concrete bases, but the ground was too hard. He learns that he will soon lose the computer, so he has the computer print out its entire stored info before it is lost.

He basically works himself to death, trying to survive. The last part describes him laying on the beach, dying of exhaustion looking at a group of curious semi intelligent amphibian aliens. He counts four of them then thinks what is the point of knowing the number of this or the number of that.  Then he fades into death.

Comment: user89108 Many thanks I can now search to see If I can get a copy, I read this back in the late 70's when serving with the Royal Navy and over the years I have thought many times that I would like to re-visit it. I am now in my sixties and hopefully will get that opportunity. One I believe would make a great film. again thanks you for your post.

Answer (score -2):

It might be Richard C. Meredith's "[We All Died at Breakaway Station](https://sciencefictionruminations.wordpress.com/2015/06/09/book-review-we-all-died-at-breakaway-station-richard-c-meredith-1969/)", in Amazing in 1968 or '69.

> Captain Absolom Bracer, with an artificial brainpan and synthetic eyes. Astrogation officer Gene O'Gwynn, a lady with a plastic face. Weapons officer Akin Darby and Communications officer Miss Cyanta, both with assorted prosthetic parts.
>
> These were the officers of the Iwo Jima, one of the two heavy battle-cruiser starships protecting the vast cumbersome Rudolph Cragston, a hospital ship returning to Earth with thousands of wounded in cold sleep.
>
> These brutally injured officers had been restored to temporary, artificial life to do this job because no intact man or woman could be spared from the main conflict.
>
> But then Breakaway Station, a vital link with Earth, was suddenly threatened..

Comment: Can you add any details that make this match the question, rather than letting it seem like a random book out of the blue?

Comment: The review I linked does not seem to match up with the question.